# Which ports are opened by default in the same security group to communicate with instances within it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

Are all ports within the same security group opened by default or should we specify them? Like for example TCP on ports 0-65535 and ICMP IPv4 on all ports?

I ask because I noticed I don't need to specify SSH port 22 within the same security group to be able to access other instances in the same security group, so I wonder if this applied to all protocols and all ports.

This is how it currently looks like. The instances within the SG have an IP in the range 172.31.80.0/20. I only allowed SSH from other security groups, not within it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, instances within the same security group can't talk to each other (over any port); there is an exception however for the default security group.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPCSecurityGroups):

> Instances associated with a security group can't talk to each other unless you add rules allowing the traffic (exception: the default security group has these rules by default).

Comment: Hmm, then I wonder why I was able to SSH from another instance without explicitly opening that port.

Comment: @Caterina are you using the default security group?

Comment: I updated the post. I am using a custom one.

Comment: those are two different security group inbound rules but within the same security group

Comment: @Caterina Right; I suspect the range of the ip addresses those CIDR blocks define include the private ip address of the instance you connected to (over SSH from the looks of it)

Comment: Ok makes sense, but how can I check this? (thx for your help btw)

Comment: @Caterina how can you check what? Try creating a new security group (which will have no inbound rules) and then attach that security group to the two instances, you'll find that the two instances won't be able to talk to each other

Comment: @Caterina you meant my statement about the CIDR blocks? Lookup a CIDR to ips converter online, and you'll find that the private ip of the instance you connected to is within those ips

Comment: Thanks, the addresses don't overlap.

Comment: @Caterina you have two CIDRs, check both. One must include it